# Fraction calculator c++

Tags: c++

Iam trying to figure out a way to add two fractions and get the result fraction in the lowest form or a mixed form depending on the output, but the problem is when i enter two fractions with the same denominator it just messes up everything else works perfectly
this is the code i have so far

```
#include<cmath>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void reduce_fraction(int &numerator, int &denominator);
void addFractions(int numerator1Par, int denominator1Par, int numerator2Par, int              denominator2Par);
int main(){
    int numerator1 = 0;
    int denominator1 = 0;
    int numerator2 = 0;
    int denominator2 = 0;
    int unfactoredNumerator = 0;
    int resultDenominator = 0;
    int mixedNumberRemainder = 0;
    int mixedNumberWhole = 0;
    int reducedNumerator = 0;
    int reducedDenominator = 0;
    int result;
    int greatCommonDenominator;
    cout << "Enter first numerator:   ";
    cin >> numerator1;

    cout << "Enter first denominator: ";
    cin >> denominator1;
    cout << endl;


    cout << "Enter second numerator:   ";
    cin >> numerator2;

    cout << "Enter second denominator: ";
    cin >> denominator2;
    cout << endl;
    if (denominator1 == denominator2)
    {
            result = numerator1 + numerator2;
            if (unfactoredNumerator>resultDenominator){
                    int a = unfactoredNumerator / resultDenominator;
                    int b = unfactoredNumerator - (a*resultDenominator);
                    cout << numerator1 << "/" << denominator1 << " + " << numerator2 << "/" << denominator2 << " = " << a << " " << b << "/" << resultDenominator << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                    if (unfactoredNumerator == 0 && resultDenominator == 0)
                            greatCommonDenominator = 1;
                    else if (resultDenominator == 0)
                            greatCommonDenominator = unfactoredNumerator;
                    else if (unfactoredNumerator != 0) {
                            int a = unfactoredNumerator, b = resultDenominator;
                            while (a != b)
                                    if (a < b)
                                            b -= a;
                                    else
                                            a -= b;
                            greatCommonDenominator = b;
                    }
                    cout << numerator1 << "/" << denominator1 << " + " << numerator2 << "/" << denominator2 << " = " << (unfactoredNumerator / greatCommonDenominator) << "/" << (resultDenominator / greatCommonDenominator) << endl;
            }

    }
    else
    {
            addFractions(numerator1, denominator1, numerator2, denominator2);
    }
    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}

void reduce_fraction(int &numerator, int &denominator)
{
    for (int i = denominator * numerator; i > 1; i--) {
            if ((denominator % i == 0) && (numerator % i == 0))
            {
                    denominator /= i;
                    numerator /= i;
            }

    }
}
void addFractions(int numerator1Par, int denominator1Par, int numerator2Par, int denominator2Par)  {
    int unfactoredNumerator;
    int resultDenominator;
    int greatCommonDenominator;
    unfactoredNumerator = numerator1Par * denominator2Par + numerator2Par * denominator1Par;
    resultDenominator = denominator1Par * denominator2Par;
    if (unfactoredNumerator>resultDenominator){
            int a = unfactoredNumerator / resultDenominator;
            int b = unfactoredNumerator - (a*resultDenominator);
            cout << numerator1Par << "/" << denominator1Par << " + " << numerator2Par << "/" << denominator2Par << " = " << a << " " << b << "/" << resultDenominator << endl;
    }
    else
    {
            if (unfactoredNumerator == 0 && resultDenominator == 0)
                    greatCommonDenominator = 1;
            else if (resultDenominator == 0)
                    greatCommonDenominator = unfactoredNumerator;
            else if (unfactoredNumerator != 0) {
                    int a = unfactoredNumerator, b = resultDenominator;
                    while (a != b)
                            if (a < b)
                                    b -= a;
                            else
                                    a -= b;
                    greatCommonDenominator = b;
            }
            cout << numerator1Par << "/" << denominator1Par << " + " << numerator2Par << "/" << denominator2Par << " = " << (unfactoredNumerator / greatCommonDenominator) << "/" << (resultDenominator / greatCommonDenominator) << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should add example in- and output showing the actual problem. "it just messes up" is not really helpfull.

Comment: oh ok sorry so if i input 5/6 and 1/10 the answer will be 14/15 which is correct , but if i enter 4/5 and 3/5 the output is 0/0 correct output should be 1 2/5 and if i input 2/9 and 16/18 the output is 1 18/162 which is also wrong the correct output should be 1 1/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the denominators are the same, you're not initializing **unfactoredNumerator** and **resultDenominator** so they are both always zero. Also you're not checking if **resultDenominator** is zero before you divide by it. (And you should check to see if any of the passed in values for numerators and denominators are zero and handle those cases accordingly.)

Comment: thank you very much i for pointing out my problems and the 1 18/162 was coming out because i had not call the function that reduces the fractions, thank you again for everyone for helping me out.